# post image restframework api with react

Tags: python, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I am working on `react application in front end and Django-rest-framework in back end

I tested the API for uploading images on postman and it works great but in the react app it return an error from backend

> `SuspiciousFileOperation at /api/change_profile_image The joined path (D:\media\profiles\user10\2_628d8.jpg) is located outside of the base path component (D:\users\sct\Scripts\R\f\media)`

here a [postman test image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30g4p.png)

and here the react function for form submit

```
const submit_avatar = async(e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const fd = new FormData()
    fd.append('avatar',e.target.files[0], e.target.files[0].name)
    fd.append('cover_image',profileInfo.cover_image)
    fd.append('email',profileInfo.email)

    const head = new FormData()
    head.append("Content-type","multipart/form-data")
    await axios
    .post("change_profile_image", fd, 
    {
        headers:{"Content-type":"multipart/form-data","Accept":"*/*"}
    }
    ).then(()=>{console.log("updated")})
}
```

and here is the [response from browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RyYK.png)

> setting.py

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

STATIC_URL = 'static/'


MEDIA_ROOT= os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
MEDIA_URL="/media/"
```

**is there any way to overcome this error, thanks in advance**

Comment: add your `setting.py`  file

Comment: @monim thank for your interest `setting.py` added

Comment: change  `STATIC_URL = 'static/'` to  `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`

Comment: @monim I am not using any static files in the project and the api work perfect on postman